# PyTorchを使った物体検出の転移学習が動作しない

Tags: python, python3, pytorch

### 概要

PyTorchのサンプルコードを参考にした転移学習コードでtrain_one_epochが動作しません
どのようにすれば学習が進みますでしょうか?

以下追記
vscode上でスクリプトを実行すると、実行中を示すアイコンが出るだけで、学習の進捗やエラーメッセージは表示されません
一方で、処理確認のために挿入したprintメッセージが、下記に添付したengine.pyの抜粋中の"start train"まで表示されることは確認済みです
この間、CPU及びGPU使用率は10%未満です

### 詳細

PyTorchのObject Detectionに関するドキュメントを参考に、自前の画像で転移学習するコードを作成しました

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html

実際に動作させるとtrain_one_epochメソッド以降処理が進まず、学習が完了しない状態となってしまいます

より詳細には、下記の箇所まで実行することを確認しております
engin.pyより抜粋

```
def train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq, scaler=None):
    print("model train")
    model.train()

    print("log")
    metric_logger = utils.MetricLogger(delimiter="  ")
    metric_logger.add_meter("lr", utils.SmoothedValue(window_size=1, fmt="{value:.6f}"))
    header = f"Epoch: [{epoch}]"

    lr_scheduler = None
    if epoch == 0:
        warmup_factor = 1.0 / 1000
        warmup_iters = min(1000, len(data_loader) - 1)

        lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LinearLR(
            optimizer, start_factor=warmup_factor, total_iters=warmup_iters
        )
    print("start train")
    #ここまでは実行される
    for images, targets in metric_logger.log_every(data_loader, print_freq, header):
        #ここから実行されない
        print("get images")
        images = list(image.to(device) for image in images)
        print("get targets")
        targets = [{k: v.to(device) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]

        print("calc loss")
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast(enabled=scaler is not None):
            loss_dict = model(images, targets)
            losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())

        # reduce losses over all GPUs for logging purposes
        print("reduce loss")
        loss_dict_reduced = utils.reduce_dict(loss_dict)
        losses_reduced = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict_reduced.values())

        print("loss value")
        loss_value = losses_reduced.item()

        if not math.isfinite(loss_value):
            print(f"Loss is {loss_value}, stopping training")
            print(loss_dict_reduced)
            sys.exit(1)

        print("optimizer calc")
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        if scaler is not None:
            scaler.scale(losses).backward()
            scaler.step(optimizer)
            scaler.update()
        else:
            losses.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        if lr_scheduler is not None:
            lr_scheduler.step()

        print("metric logger")
        metric_logger.update(loss=losses_reduced, **loss_dict_reduced)
        metric_logger.update(lr=optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"])

    return metric_logger
```

### 環境

Windows 10
GPU: GTX 1080Ti
Python==3.9.13
torch==1.13.1+cu116
torchaudio==0.13.1+cu116
torchvision==0.14.1+cu116
notebook==6.5.2

torch.cuda.is_available()がTrueであることは確認済みです

### コード

作成したコードを添付します
Jupyter Notebookで作成したコードをPythonにエクスポートしております

```
# %%
from pycocotools.coco import COCO
import os
import numpy as np
import torch
from PIL import Image
import glob
from typing import Tuple


# %%
class COCODataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root, transform=None) -> None:
        self.coco = COCO(os.path.join(root, "metadata.json"))
        self.images = list(glob.glob(os.path.join(root, "*.bmp")))
        self.transform = transform

    
    def __getitem__(self, idx: int) :
        image = Image.open(self.images[idx]).convert("RGB")

        obj_ids = self.coco.getAnnIds(idx)
        boxes, areas = [], []
        for obj_id in obj_ids:
            ann = self.coco.anns[obj_id]
            boxes += [ann["bbox"]]
            areas += [ann["area"]]

        #マスク画像がないためサンプルコードから該当処理は削除
        target = {}
        target["image_id"] = torch.tensor([idx])
        target["labels"] = torch.ones((len(obj_ids)), dtype=torch.int64)
        target["boxes"] = torch.as_tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.float32)
        target["area"] = torch.as_tensor(areas, dtype=torch.float32)
        target["iscrowd"] = torch.zeros((len(obj_ids)), dtype=torch.int64)

        if self.transform is not None:
            image, target = self.transform(image, target)

        return (image, target)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.images)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        attrs = vars(self)
        string = ", ".join("%s: %s" % item for item in attrs.items())
        return string


# %%
import torchvision
from torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn import FastRCNNPredictor

# %%
def get_instance_segmentation_model(num_classes):
    # load a model pre-trained pre-trained on COCO
    model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)

    # get the number of input features for the classifier
    in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
    # replace the pre-trained head with a new one
    model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)

    return model

# %%
from engine import train_one_epoch, evaluate
import utils
import transforms as T

def get_transform(train):
    transforms = []
    # converts the image, a PIL image, into a PyTorch Tensor
    transforms.append(T.PILToTensor())
    if train:
        # during training, randomly flip the training images
        # and ground-truth for data augmentation
        transforms.append(T.RandomHorizontalFlip(0.5))
    return T.Compose(transforms)

# %%
# use our dataset and defined transformations
dataset_root_path = "../DataSet/train"
dataset = COCODataset(dataset_root_path, get_transform(train=True))
dataset_test = COCODataset(dataset_root_path, get_transform(train=False))

# split the dataset in train and test set
torch.manual_seed(1)
indices = torch.randperm(len(dataset)).tolist()
dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, indices[:-50])
dataset_test = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset_test, indices[-50:])

# define training and validation data loaders
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, num_workers=4,
    collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)

data_loader_test = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset_test, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=4,
    collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)

# %%
dataset[0]

# %%
device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')

# 教師データは、背景と対象の2クラスのみです
num_classes = 2

# ヘルパー関数を使用してモデルを取得します
model = get_instance_segmentation_model(num_classes)
# モデルを適切なデバイスに移動します
model.to(device)

# オプティマイザを構築します
params = [p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params, lr=0.005,
                            momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)

# 学習率を3エポックごとに10分の1に減らす学習率スケジューラ
lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer,
                                               step_size=3,
                                               gamma=0.1)

# %%
# let's train it for 10 epochs
num_epochs = 10

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # train for one epoch, printing every 10 iterations
    print("epoch start")
    train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
    # update the learning rate
    print("train done")
    lr_scheduler.step()
    # evaluate on the test dataset
    print("start evaluate")
    evaluate(model, data_loader_test, device=device)
```

Comment: 「train_one_epochメソッド以降処理が進まず、学習が完了しない状態」とはもう少し具体的には何でしょうか？（jupyterカーネルが死んでしまう、CPUが100%に張り付いてしまう etc）また、OSやGPUの有無についても質問に追記されると良いかと思います。

Comment: @merino 
問題と環境について補足いたしました